# Не заносится в память размерность моей матрицы из текстового файла. Вот мой код

Tags: c, матрицы

Вот моя реализация, оцените

```
void openprint (int **x, int *n, int *m){
int j , i,k;
FILE *f;
char name [25];
printf ("enter the name of the file");
scanf ("%s", name);
if((f=fopen(name,"r"))==NULL){
    printf ("file not found");
    system ("PAUSE");
    
    }

fscanf (f,"%d%d", n, m) ;

x=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*   *n);
for(i=0;i< *n;i++)
x[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*  *m);
for(i=0;i< *n;i++)
 for(j=0;j< *m;j++)
 fscanf(f,"%d", &x[i][j]);
fclose(f);
printf(" matrix:\n") ;
for(i=0;i< *n;i++){
    for(j=0;j< *m;j++)
     printf ("%3d", x[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Аргумент `int **x` => `int ***x` Это изменит адрес `int**p` извне.

Answer (score 1):

Всё читается, только вы выделенную память не сохраняете наружу и указатель на неё теряется в стеке.

```
void openprint (int **x, int *n, int *m){
```

=>

```
void openprint (int ***xp , int *n, int *m){
  ..
  * xp = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*   *n);
  int * * x = * xp ;
  ..
```

вызов :

```
int * * x ;
int n ;
int m ;
openprint ( & x , & n, & m);
```